# Mirror edit mesh, after UVs are done

Tags: modeling, mirror-modifier

I am coming from Maya to Blender.
I know I can apply mirror modifier on mesh, and it will automatically mirror from the side I am editing.
Maya also has that, but it also has a mirror tools, that can recognize similar geometry on defined side. This means I can create a model, then do UVs, and continue mirror edit the model.

In Blender case, I have to delete half geometry, to again apply mirror modifier, which will also deletes UV maps that I created.

Is there a way to mirror edit without this deformer, like in Maya?

Thank you.

Comment: At the top right of the 3D view there's a Enable mesh symmetry option and you just the symmetry axis (X, Y or Z), is it what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked before posting. Blender has exact behavior as Maya does.

While Move tool is selected, In tool settings on the right shelf (press N), there are mirror axis buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to open the N panel, the *Enable mesh symmetry* options are at the top right of your 3D view:

[image]